Is this an error in Hermann Weyl's Space-Time-Matter, and what should it say?
There are countless errors in the English translation of Hermann Weyl's Space-Time-Matter.  I can usually resolve these by referring to the German original.  In this rare instance, the error seems to be in the original which I have provided in facsimile below.
This sentence doesn't make sense to me: It is then evident from the form of the expression that $Q(\mathfrak{y})$ must be negative unless $\mathfrak{y} = \mathfrak{0}$.
The vector $\mathfrak{y}$ is essentially arbitrary, so $Q\left(\mathfrak{y}\right)$ can have any real value.  Also, since $\mathfrak{y}$ is a linear combination of $r+1$ linearly independent vectors $\mathfrak{y}=\sum_{i=1}^{r}\mathfrak{e}_{i}\lambda_{i}+\mathfrak{x}$ then $\mathfrak{y}=\mathfrak{0}\implies\mathfrak{x}=\mathfrak{0}.$  So that doesn't seem very informative.
I'm guessing Weyl intended to say $Q\left(\mathfrak{x}\right)\le 0$ and $Q\left(\mathfrak{x}\right)= 0\iff\mathfrak{x}=\mathfrak{0}.$ The final sentence would then be something like If $Q\left(\mathfrak{y}\right)=0$ and $\lambda_{i\le r}=0$ then $\mathfrak{x}=\mathfrak{0}.$
Is the original text incorrect? Is my suggestion a reasonable correction?

An important corollary is to be made in the indefinite case. The numbers $r$ and $s$ attached to the $\epsilon_{i}$'s, and having positive and negative signs respectively, are uniquely determined by the quadratic form: it may be said to have $r$ positive and $s$ negative dimensions. ($s$ may be called the inertial index of the quadratic
form, and the theorem just enunciated is known by the name
Law of Inertia. The classification of surfaces of the second order depends on it.) The numbers $r$ and $s$ may be characterised
invariantly thus:---


There are $r$ mutually orthogonal vectors $\mathfrak{e}$, for which $Q(\mathfrak{e}) > 0$;
but for a vector $\mathfrak{x}$ which is orthogonal to these and not equal to $\mathfrak{0}$, it necessarily follows that $Q(\mathfrak{x}) < 0$. Consequently there cannot
be more than $r$ such vectors. A corresponding theorem holds
for $s$.


$r$ vectors of the required type are given by those $r$ fundamental
vectors  $\mathfrak{e}_{i}$ of the co-ordinate system upon which the
expression  Eq(14) is founded, to which the positive signs $\epsilon_{i}$ correspond.
The corresponding components $x_{i}$ ($i = 1, 2, 3, \dots, r$) are
definite linear forms of $\mathfrak{x}$ [cf. Eq(16)]: $x_{i} = L_{i}(\mathfrak{x})$. If, now, $\mathfrak{e}_{i}$
($i = 1, 2, \dots, r$) is any system of vectors which are mutually
orthogonal to one another, and satisfy the condition $Q(\mathfrak{e}_{i}) > 0$, and
if $\mathfrak{x}$ is a vector orthogonal to these $\mathfrak{e}_{i}$, we can set up a linear combination
$$\mathfrak{y} = \lambda_{1}\mathfrak{e}_{1} + \dots + \lambda_{r}\mathfrak{e}_{r} + \mu \mathfrak{x}
$$
in which not all the co-efficients vanish and which satisfies the $r$ homogeneous
equations
$$L_{1}(\mathfrak{x}) = 0,\quad \dots
L_{r}(\mathfrak{y}) = 0.
$$
$\color{red}{\text{It is then evident from the form of the expression that } Q(\mathfrak{y}) \text{ must
be negative unless } \mathfrak{y} = \mathfrak{0}}$. In virtue of the formula
$$Q(\mathfrak{y}) - \bigl\{\lambda_{1}^{2} Q(\mathfrak{e}_{1}) + \dots + \lambda_{r}^{2} Q(\mathfrak{e}_{r})\bigr\}
  = \mu^{2} Q(\mathfrak{x})$$
it then follows that $Q(\mathfrak{x}) < 0$ except in the case in which if $\mathfrak{y} = \mathfrak{0}$,
$\lambda_{1} = \dots = \lambda_{r}$ also $= 0$. But then, by hypothesis, $\mu$ must $\neq 0$, i.e. $\mathfrak{x} = \mathfrak{0}$.




You are mistaken, this vector is not "arbitrary" as it satisfies the equations $L_i=0$, $i=1,...,r$. Weyl is right.

Oh.  I see.  The error was in the translation.  I didn't examine the original closely enough.
